# Require help with css, Autosuggest jquery by Drew Wilson

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autosuggest

Because of stackoverflows spam prevention, links + image are in pastebin. [HERE](http://pastebin.com/sbHb9U28)

On with question-

I want it so when I click an autosuggest it works as a link but that isn't the main question here.

If you go on my website (pastebin) you can see there are boxes around the text box.

[Please look at the image, also in pastebin] (Drew's form ontop, mine below)

It must be css, but I can not find which property has to be changed.
(the form is generated on-the-fly so I can't look at the html.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pal, thats because you have called the plugin twice at `$(document).ready`.

---

Remove the following from your `$(document).ready`.

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest(data);
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/H7ptB/

Comment: Ah right, I see! 
thanks :)
oh so simple, I didn't read the (poor) documentation properly

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out all the border properties and box shadow properties in the Auto Suggest CSS file.